# Updating dictionary with another k/v in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I hate to ask this but I can't figure it out and it's getting to me.

I have to make a function that takes a given dictionary `d1` and sort of compares it to another dictionary `d2` then adds the compared value to `d2`.

`d1` is already in the format needed to I don't have to worry about it.
`d2` however, is a nested dictionary. It looks like this:

```
{’345’: {’Name’: ’xyzzy’, ’ID’: ’345’, ’Responses’: {’Q3’: ’c’, ’Q1’: ’a’, ’Q4’: ’b’, ’Q2’: ’a’}},
’123’: {’Name’: ’foo’, ’ID’: ’123’, ’Responses’: {’Q3’: ’c’, ’Q1’: ’a’, ’Q4’: ’a’, ’Q2’: ’b’}},
’234’: {’Name’: ’bar’, ’ID’: ’234’, ’Responses’: {’Q3’: ’c’, ’Q1’: ’a’, ’Q4’: ’b’, ’Q2’: ’b’}}}
```

So `d1` is in the format of the `Responses` key, and that's what I need from `d2` to compare it to `d1`.

So to do that I isolate `responses`:

```
    for key, i in d2.items():
    temp = i['Responses']
```

Now I need to run temp through a function with `d1` that will output an integer. Then match that integer with the top-level key it came from and update a new k/v entry associated with it. But I don't know how to do this.

I've managed to update each top-level key with that compared value, but it only uses the first compared value for all the top-level keys. I can't figure out how to match the integer found to its key. This is what I have so far that works the best:

```
    for  i in d2:
        score = grade_student(d1,temp)        #integer
        placement = {'Score': score}
        d2[i].update(placement)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just iterate over sub dictionaries in `d2` and update them once you've called `grade_student`:

```
for v in d2.values():
    v['Score'] = grade_student(d1, v['Responses'])
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import pprint

d1 = {}
d2 = {
    '345': {'Name': 'xyzzy', 'ID': '345', 'Responses': {'Q3': 'c', 'Q1': 'a', 'Q4': 'b', 'Q2': 'a'}},
    '123': {'Name': 'foo', 'ID': '123', 'Responses': {'Q3': 'c', 'Q1': 'a', 'Q4': 'a', 'Q2': 'b'}},
    '234': {'Name': 'bar', 'ID': '234', 'Responses': {'Q3': 'c', 'Q1': 'a', 'Q4': 'b', 'Q2': 'b'}}
}

# Dummy
def grade_student(x, y):
    return 1

for v in d2.values():
    v['Score'] = grade_student(d1, v['Responses'])

pprint.pprint(d2)
```

Output:

```
{'123': {'ID': '123',
         'Name': 'foo',
         'Responses': {'Q1': 'a', 'Q2': 'b', 'Q3': 'c', 'Q4': 'a'},
         'Score': 1},
 '234': {'ID': '234',
         'Name': 'bar',
         'Responses': {'Q1': 'a', 'Q2': 'b', 'Q3': 'c', 'Q4': 'b'},
         'Score': 1},
 '345': {'ID': '345',
         'Name': 'xyzzy',
         'Responses': {'Q1': 'a', 'Q2': 'a', 'Q3': 'c', 'Q4': 'b'},
         'Score': 1}}
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use these comments for thanks, but holy shit thank you. Would have never thought to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to iterate them. Use the built-in `update()` method. Here is an example

```
>>> A = {'cat':10, 'dog':5, 'rat':50}
>>> B =  {'cat':5, 'dog':10, 'pig':20}
>>> A.update(B) #This will merge the dicts by keeping the values of B if collision
>>> A
{'rat': 50, 'pig': 20, 'dog': 10, 'cat': 5}
>>> B
{'pig': 20, 'dog': 10, 'cat': 5}
```

Comment: I did try that, but it only updated 1 of the 3 top level keys. That's why I tried to iterate.

Comment: Actually it doesn't update one of the keys, it actually just adds another k/v entry separate from the keys.